# Does dual wielding looting swords stack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does holding two Looting III swords add together? Can I get higher drops with both?

Answer (score 3):

Holding two looting swords will not add both together. Only the sword you killed the enemy with will count.

Comment: As far as I know, the enchantment of the item in the off hand is never considered. There is a notable exception: When holding a Bane of Arthropods weapon in the off-hand, the slowness effect is applied when hitting a spider, even though the damage is not transferred. I'd consider this a bug though.

Answer (score 0):

They don't add together, only the main hand can apply the Looting lvl.. You've noticed you only use 1 sword